# Not able to access elements from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I fetched my response by hitting an API and pushed each element of the response(which is an array of objects) onto an array in the state i.e mydata

```
state={
      mydata:[]
}

 componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    Axios.get("/getmeetings", {
            headers
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log(res);
                res.data.forEach((e, i) => {
                    this.state.mydata.push(e)
                })

            } else {
                alert(res);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to access the length of  my state variable it gives it as `0`
I tried printing the array and I can see that there are values available.

I also checked if my state variable was getting correctly populated using the chrome react extension.

Now another weird thing is when I hardcoded another object into the `mydata` variable

```
state= {
     mydate = [{name:"temp"},{age:"1234"}]
}
```

and then again pushed my responses onto that array and later when I checked its length, it gives me `2`. When I tried to print that array it shows those 2 objects plus my other pushed objects.

This is a sample object I'm trying to push

```
{
  "agenda": "sadsadasd",
  "project": "ECAM",
  "meeting_title": "asdasd",
  "meeting_id": "1588072890",
  "attendees": [
    "a@#$$",
    "a@a"
  ],
  "date": "1588072890",
  "host": "a@a"
}
```

Comment: Please read the React docs carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider avoiding direct push since it will **mutate** the state. Use `setState` function instead.

```
this.setState(({ myData }) => ({ myData: [...myData, res.data] }));
```

Comment: Oops my bad. I directly pushed earlier and i worked so it thought it will have no effect.